# How to group by one of two columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table of the form:

```
CREATE TABLE Messages ( 
    id   VARCHAR(40), 
    src  VARCHAR(40), 
    dest VARCHAR(40), 
    time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
);
```

I want to write a query which will return a list of all ids (either the src or dest field) along with the message id which corresponds to the newest message. I dont quite understand how to use `GROUP BY` in this way. Furthermore, this query needs to be fast (which is why i dont want to simply union two queries: one for src and one for dest). Ultimately though, performance is key, regardless of how it is done.

Sample Data:

```
id, src, dest, time
0,  0,   1,    '2012-10-19 01:15:15'
1,  1,   0,    '2012-10-20 01:15:15'
2,  0,   1,    '2012-09-19 01:15:15'
3,  1,   0,    '2012-04-20 01:15:15'
4,  2,   1,    '2013-04-20 01:15:15'
5,  1,   0,    '2012-04-20 01:15:15'
```

Expected output:

```
id, person
1,  0
4,  1
4,  2
```

Current query:

```
SELECT m1.id,m1.src AS person FROM Messages m1 WHERE m1.time IS (SELECT MAX(time) FROM Messages m2 WHERE m2.src=m1.src OR m2.dest=m1.src)
UNION
SELECT m1.id,m1.dest AS person FROM Messages m1 WHERE m1.time IS (SELECT MAX(time) FROM Messages m2 WHERE m1.dest=m2.dest OR m1.dest=m2.src)
```

However, this takes 19.99sec for a table with 5163 rows. The query had 26,661,730 steps.

Comment: You should post what you have tried. That gives us more detail, and we can quickly give an answer by copy-pasting the code with minor modifications.

Comment: Or rahter show us some sample data please :) along the expected output.

Comment: In regards to performance, what are your indexed columns?

Comment: "Here's my table definition. Write my code for me" is not an acceptable question here. Post what you've tried so far that isn't working for you, and we'll try and help you figure out how to make it work or improve it. SO is not a code or SQL writing service.

Comment: @KenWhite as I said, I dont know how to write it because of the groupby problem

Comment: @chacham15 I still think that the "expected output" needs to be included. Also, please avoid "best" or "fastest" from titles. In any case, original down-vote removed, but I still think it needs improvement.

Comment: @pst sry, im juggling too much. The question is for the fastest way, not just any way. Is there better way to ask that?

Comment: @chacham15 Just ask for a way in the title - show any relevant code/query already used (and how it is insufficient). Most people serious about SQL will provide "fast" solutions and/or indicate shortcomings or requirements. Now, once a *working way* is used, then *that* might be able to be refined, but it requires an existing query along with performance numbers.

Comment: @nawfal I added a query which works but is terribly slow as a solution. Hopefully we can improve that somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem with your query is not the `union` but rather the correlated subquery.  Here is an approach that uses a trick to get the id associated with the maximum time.  It appends the id onto the end of the time and then applies the `max()` function:

```
select substr(MAX(maxtime||maxtimeid), 19) as id, person
from (select src as person, substr(MAX(sent||CAST(id as varchar(20))), 19) as maxtimeid, MAX(sent) as maxtime
       from Messages
       group by src
       union all
      select dest as person, substr(MAX(sent||CAST(id as varchar(20))), 19) as maxtimeid, MAX(sent) as maxtime
       from Messages
       group by dest
     )
group by person
```

Although this query has aggregations, it has no joins.  Try it out and see if you get better performance.  Note that I have not tested this, so there might be small syntax errors.

I don't know the relative performance of a union versus an outer join in SQLite.  But, you can also phrase this as:

```
select (case when src.maxtime > dest.maxtime or dest.maxtime is null
             then src.maxtimeid
             else dest.maxtimeid
        end) as id,
       coalesce(src.person, dest.person) as person
from (select src as person, substr(MAX(sent||CAST(id as varchar(20))), 19) as maxtimeid, MAX(sent) as maxtime
       from Messages
       group by src
      ) src full outer join
      (select dest as person, substr(MAX(sent||CAST(id as varchar(20))), 19) as maxtimeid, MAX(sent) as maxtime
       from Messages
       group by dest
     ) dest
     on src.person = dest.person
```

Comment: i corrected the sql, but indeed this does run much faster: at 36.35 ms.

Comment: Note that you can probably tweak a little bit more performance out by using `union all` instead of `union`.  I also gave another way of getting the same information.

Comment: SQLite does not support outer joins

Comment: Oh well.  At least the `union all` method works.  SQLite does support `left outer join`.  So, if you knew that all persons originated a message, then you could try that.

Comment: What im trying to figure out is why the query I wrote returns 158 rows and the query you wrote returns 234.

Comment: My query should return one row for each person.  I can imagine reasons why your query would return *more* rows than mine (you'll have duplicates for persons as both src and dest).  The only way I can think that you would get fewer rows is if the src/dest fields take on NULL values.

Comment: I actually just noticed that somehow the outer query is attaching what seems to be 2 characters to the front of id, why? Also: its two of the same number from 0-9 (00,11,22,...)

Comment: @chacham15 . . . Perhaps because I cannot count.  Or because the internal format for the datetime has time to the tenth of a second.  In any case, just change the 19 to 21 (or perhaps 20) to fix this problem.

Comment: I was thinking about that but `SELECT DISTINCT LENGTH(CAST(time AS TEXT)) FROM Messages;` returns 19. Furthermore, the inner queries are returning proper values...